# Flaming Ulitmate Sword

Tags: dungeon-defenders, xbox-network

I played with a Monk on xbox live that was doing 1.3Million dps with his giant flaming sword at level 12.

I am guessing this sword is the result of some quest or premium. The sword essentially maxed out his stats (he did not gain anything by increasing them more with other items) and one slash killed most monsters we faced.

Anyone know what it is or could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mordenkainen's Magical Flaming Dragons is the sword title I believe you are looking for.

It is obtained via the monsterfest challenge on easy/med.

Comment: I assume that people play this challenge with some high level then give it to their noob?

Comment: @Chad I recommend for you to try not to, but the majority of people I would assume do, so Yes.  Another means of doing this would be playing in a modded match.  One of my friends accidentally joined one and on one hit while in party, he hit max lvl. lol.

Comment: Did this answer your question @Chad ?  If so, hit check! :)

Comment: I was actually more concerned that I was playing with someone hacking or cheating.  I think it kind of defeats playing the game if you cheat like that but would be fun to give an noob and watch him walk through some of the challenges.